# What is $2^{300} \pmod{323}$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have been told to use Fermat-Euler theorem. Using it, I get to $2^{(323)(288)} \equiv 1 \pmod{323}$, but I am not sure where to go from there!

Comment: do you mean $$2^{300} \mod 323$$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) for a compendium of techniques needed to do problems like this. IMO this is a duplicate, but I have promised not to vote to close "abstract duplicates" given that my vote would be immediately binding.

Answer (score 3):

We know $\varphi(323)=288$. This means 
$$2^{288}\equiv 1\mod 323$$
Thus,
$$2^{300}\equiv2^{300-288}\equiv2^{12}\mod 323$$
And $2^{12}=4096$, so from this point on, there's no large numbers to worry about.

To finish the calculation simply note that $2^{12}\equiv 4096\equiv 220\mod 323$, and thus

$$2^{300}\equiv 220\mod 323$$

Answer (score 0):

**Method**$\#1:$

As $323=17\cdot19$

$2^4\equiv-1\pmod{17}\implies2^8\equiv1$ as $300\equiv4\pmod8,2^{300}\equiv2^4\pmod{17}\equiv-1\ \ \ \ (1)$

$2^9\equiv-1\pmod{19}\implies2^{18}\equiv1,300\equiv-6\pmod{18},$

$2^{300}\equiv2^{-6}\pmod{19}\equiv7^{-1}\equiv11\ \ \ \  (2)$ as $7\cdot11\equiv1\pmod{19}$

Apply CRT on $(1),(2)$

**Method**$\#2:$

$\lambda(323)=$lcm$(17-1,19-1)=144$

$300\equiv12\pmod{144}\implies2^{300}\equiv2^{12}\pmod{323}\equiv?$